# Cloudformation script stack building use existing s3 bucket instead of creating new (Error: s3-bucket-name already exists)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am creating an AWS cloudformation script to create a S3 bucket and notification event to trigger a Lambda.  As part of it, if s3 bucket is not created already, it creates s3 bucket and everything works fine.

But if S3 bucket was already there, then getting error.

**`Error: s3-bucket-name already exists`**

```
"S3Bucket" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties" : {
            "BucketName" : {
                "Ref": "s3-bucket-name"
            },
            "NotificationConfiguration" : {
                "LambdaConfigurations" : [ {
                    "Event" : "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                    "Filter" : {
                        ...
                    },
                    "Function" : {
                        "Fn::Sub": "<your-lambda-arn>"
                    }
                }]
        ...
}
```

AWS cloudformation stack should use the bucket if already exist.  and create if not exist.

I might be missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the bucket hasn't been created by your templates, AWS will simply assume that you are trying to create a second bucket having the same name as the existing one. Of course you can't do this, as buckets must have unique names. Thus you are getting `s3-bucket-name already exists` error.

To bring existing buckets created outside CloudFormation under control of CloudFormation, you need to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) them.

S3 buckets are [one of the resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) which can be imported into CloudFormation if they already exist.

Comment: Awesome.  You guided me into right direction.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems the import existing resource expects cloud formation script of the existing resource.  In case if the bucket created manually, how can we import them ?